# Compute vertex valence of a mesh OpenMesh

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, mesh, vertex, openmesh

It's the first time I use OpenMesh and I am trying to do a very simple function to compute the valence of all vertex in a mesh.

My first attempt looks like this

```
Mesh::VertexIter vIterator, vBegin, vEnd;
Mesh::HalfedgeHandle initialEdge, nextEdge;

vBegin = mesh_.vertices_begin();
vEnd = mesh_.vertices_end();

int vertexValence;

for (vIterator = vBegin; vIterator != vEnd; ++vIterator) {
    initialEdge = mesh_.halfedge_handle(vIterator.handle());
    nextEdge = mesh_.next_halfedge_handle(initialEdge);
    vertexValence = 0;
    while (nextEdge != initialEdge) {
        vertexValence++;
        nextEdge = mesh_.next_halfedge_handle(nextEdge);
    }
    if(vIterator == vBegin){
        std::cout << "myCount = " << vertexValence << std::endl;  // prints 2
        std::cout << "meshCount = "<< mesh_.valence(vIterator)<< std::endl;  // prints 10
    }
}
```

The valence count is different from what the mesh counts (see std::cout). I know I am missing something, can anyone see where's the error?

**UPDATE**

I made it work by using the following code

```
for(vIterator = vBegin; vIterator != vEnd; ++vIterator){
    vertexValence = 0;
    for (voIterator = mesh_.voh_iter(vIterator); voIterator; ++voIterator) {
        vertexValence++;
    }
    if(vIterator == vBegin){
        std::cout << "myCount = " << vertexValence << std::endl;
        std::cout << "openMeshCount = " << mesh_.valence(vIterator) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now both numbers match. However, I would like to know if it is possible to implement the same with the first code I put. The idea should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this :

```
for (vIterator = vBegin; vIterator != vEnd; ++vIterator) {
    vertexValence = 0;
    initialEdge = mesh_.halfedge_handle(vIterator.handle());
    nextEdge = initialEdge;

    do {
        vertexValence++;
        oppositeEdge = mesh_.opposite_halfedge_handle(nextEdge);
        nextEdge = mesh_.next_halfedge_handle(oppositeEdge);
    } while (initialEdge != nextEdge);
}
```

You have to use the opposite halfedge to go back to the original vertex, take a look at [this page](http://www.openmesh.org/index.php?id=228), there is a brief description of the halfedge data structure.

Comment: Yes I just realized I was going around a triangle with my first code. Thanks for this, I think something similar is behind my second code.